# Tables persist after manually deleting database?

Tags: php, sql, database

After I navigate to my database in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data and delete the folder the tables are still saved somehow. When I try to run my PHP script again I get this error: "Error creating users table: Table '`databaseName`.`tableName`' already exists."

The line of code that triggers that error is this:

```
mysql_query($createTableQuery) or die('Error creating users table: ' . mysql_error());
```

In order to fix this problem I have to rename the tables and re-run the script. It is becoming quite cumbersome having to find new table names every time I delete my database while testing my code.

Is anyone aware of a command to delete the tables as well? Or perhaps where the tables are stored on my computer so that I could manually delete them? I'd prefer to stay away from commands and rather know exactly where these tables were stored so that I could find them and delete them.

Comment: Are we talking innodb tables? They are saved differently. Did you shutdown the server before doing the manual delete? Why not do a simple DROP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of (?):

```
DROP TABLE [name];
```

Comment: Yes but where are these tables stored on my hard drive? Are they possible to manually delete? I'm curious to their filenames.

Comment: Check out my.ini for 'datadir'

Comment: Yeah the datadir is "datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/" I knew that already. I deleted the database from there manually already but the tables are apparently stored elsewhere.

Comment: I do not know the internal MySQL storage mechanisms, but I suppose that actual tables and it's data may be stored in Data directory, but some associations/relations/connections if you wish, are stored everywhere in dbms, so deleting table's data manually, does not delete the connections to that data.

Comment: @John: it depends on your Storage Engine.

Comment: I'm just using PHP and MySQL downloaded directly from their respective websites. Vanilla for Windows 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `drop database`

not deleting the files. There may be metadata stored elsewhere.

> I'd prefer to stay away from commands
>   and rather know exactly where these
>   tables were stored so that I could
>   find them and delete them.

This is naive way of thinking. Use the public interface (SQL) not the filesystem. What will you do if the storage mechnism changes? There are many storage engines in mysql and they all don't work the same way.

Comment: Yeah I will be using commands for now on but I am still currently curious as to where the tables are stored in my filesystem.